# Remove a word from string till the next occurrence of space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of huge size from which I need to remove a word from string through JavaScript. I know the prefix of the word and I need to remove it till the next space occurs.
Here is a part of the string:

*Change of Govt. in State - `@page-SCW5016` Tenders invited*

From here I need to remove the `@page-SCW5016` and the sentence would become:

*Change of Govt. in State - Tenders invited*

In this problem, the prefix of the text to be removed will stay the same i.e. `@page-`

Comment: Try word boundary `.replace(/@page-\w+\s/, '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
var str = "Change of Govt. in State - @page-SCW5016 Tenders invited";
var reg = /@page-[A-Za-z0-9]*\s/
str = str.replace(reg,'');

console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regex replace

`\w+` - word boundary

```js
let str = "Change of Govt. in State - @page-SCW5016 Tenders invited"

let res = str.replace(/@page-\w+\s/, '')

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution for your question

```
Example 1:
var str = 'Change of Govt. in State - @page-SCW5016 @page- Tenders invited';
var cleanString = str.replace(/@page-[a-zA-z0-9]*\s/g, "");

Example 2:
var str = 'My waols @page-cksdjcsdcb invited';
var cleanString = str.replace(/@page-\w+\s/g, "");
console.log(cleanString)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let sentence = "Change of Govt. in State - @page-SCW5016 Tenders invited";

let formattedSentence = sentence.replace(/@page-\w+\s/, '');

console.log(formattedSentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let text = "Change of Govt. in State - @page-SCW5016 Tenders invited";
 let newText =text.replace(/@page-SCW5016/g,"");
```

Comment: This does not handle the OP's specifications, of matching all the way to the next space.